# How to get the value in the combo box inside the dataGridview and put in my SQL Select Query?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to get the value of the combo box call dcourse to put it in my Sql select query but it is not working. this is my code

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
     dgEdit.DataSource = dt;

     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dcourse = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     dcourse.HeaderText = "Course";
     dcourse.Items.Add("AT (Automotive Technology)");
     dcourse.Items.Add("CPT (Computer Technology)");
     dcourse.Items.Add("ELT (Electrical Technology)");
     dcourse.Items.Add("ICT (Instrumentation and Control Technology)");

     dgEdit.Columns.Add(dcourse);

     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dname = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     dname.HeaderText = "Student Name";
     conn.Open();
     cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandText = "Select Name from TBL_Student WHERE Course = '" + 
     dgEdit.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + "' ";
     DataTable dat = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     dap.Fill(dat);
     foreach (DataRow dr in dat.Rows)
     {
        dname.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
     }
     conn.Close();
     dgEdit.Columns.Add(dname);
```

i am getting this pop up window and "dgEdit.CurrentRow.Cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU2sj.png).Value" this should be the dcourse

[image: this is the error]

Comment: `it is not working.` what does it mean? Are you getting any error? is it inserting wrong value? Your does not use value of `dcourse` anywhere in the SQL query.

Comment: Please, elaborate "is not working". Do you have an *exception* thrown (what, where and with which message), *incorrect value* read (what are expected and actual one), *compile time error* (at which line and with what message)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information it is edited now